# How to call a function or tell if a MKPointAnnotation is clicked on a MKMapView SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkpointannotation

I've been trying to call a function when a pin on my map is clicked. I have about ten pins on my map, so how can I determine which pin is pressed and have all the data that the MKPointAnnotation contains?

How each annotation is added to the map:

```
 let map = MKMapView(frame: .zero)
 let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

 annotation.coordinate = donator.coordinates
 annotation.title = donator.name
 annotation.subtitle = donator.car
 map.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could add a tap gesture recognizer to `MKAnnotationView`

Comment: SwiftUI iOS 14 MapKit Annotation with Tap Gesture link at apple developers forum - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659748?answerId=655389022#655389022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're wrapping your `MKMapView` inside a `UIViewRepresentable` struct, add a coordinator with the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol to listen for changes on your map:

```
//Inside your UIViewRepresentable struct
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator()
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
    //Delegate function to listen for annotation selection on your map
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        if let annotation = view.annotation {
            //Process your annotation here
        }
    }
}
```

There are a couple of tutorials out there on how to include an MKMapView in SwiftUI and use delegation to access the `MKMapViewDelegate` functions through `UIViewRepresentable` and coordinators.

Following along my suggestion, your previous code would look like so:

```
struct MapKitView: UIViewRepresentable {

    typealias Context = UIViewRepresentableContext<MapKitView>

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let map = MKMapView()
        map.delegate = context.coordinator
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        annotation.coordinate = donator.coordinates
        annotation.title = donator.name
        annotation.subtitle = donator.car
        map.addAnnotation(annotation)
        return map
    }

    //Coordinator code
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator { ... }
}
```